# Installed npm packages dont work

Tags: node.js, terminal

I have npm installed and I've installed a couple of packages, but every time I run a package it returns a `command not found`.

When I run `which npm` it returns **/usr/local/bin/npm**

I have installed **bower**, although it happens with all npm packages, but, for example, when I run `bower` is returns:

```
$ bower
-bash: bower: command not found
```

Any clues on what is causing npm packages not to work?

Comment: @hazelnoot Do you know which path should the `npm config prefix` match with?

Comment: You have to set the global prefix to something in your $PATH. @GEspinha